# Trimming all leading and trailing namespaces after splitting the word

Tags: c#, string

I have a scenario in C#:
Input is->

```
Sachin.Dutta :  trimbegging space :: delete spaceafter
```

Expected output->

```
Sachin.Dutta:trimbegging space::delete spaceafter
```

First,I need to split the string based on : or :: 
Then trim whitespaces from beginning and end of every word
Then combine the words to get expected output.

I can write code using for loop to separate words and again recombine them.But,is there any better way using LINQ or Regex for this ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow! Here we dealing with code (with not working code, mostly). If your code is actually working as expected and you what to just enhance it a little - there is [another stackexchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this.

Comment: no evidence that you've tried anything yourself

Comment: How your expected output contains `space` and `spaceafter`?

Comment: @er-sho space and spaceafter are words ,they do not mean " "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Regex with pattern `@"\s*:\s*"`

```
var input = "Sachin.Dutta :  trimbegging space :: delete spaceafter";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s*:\s*", ":");
```

**Output**

```
Sachin.Dutta:trimbegging space::delete spaceafter
```

---

**Explanation**

- `\s*` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `:` matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
- `\s*` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)